# How to create/use \.Identifier at SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, pager

I have used pod to create paging scroll:

https://github.com/fermoya/SwiftUIPager

However, there are some errors which are not described well enough.

[image: UI]

1. I have created

   ```
   struct ContentView: View {
       @State private var page = 0
       ...
   }
   ```
2. `self.levels = ["img1", "img2"...]`

   3.

   ```
   struct cardView: View {

   var item : String
   @Binding var page: Int
   let screenW = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
   let screenH = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
   let sceneButtonH = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.6494
   let sceneButtonW = (UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.6494) * 1.0867
   let buttonPadding = ((UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.6494) * 1.0867) * 0.26

   var body: some View{

           Button(action: {
               //self.showingDetail.toggle()
           }) {
               Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: item )!)
                   .renderingMode(.original)
                   .resizable()
                   .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                   .padding(.leading, buttonPadding/2)
                   .padding(.trailing, buttonPadding/2)
           }
   }

   }
   ```

How to create .identifier? It is a custom method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code, assuming `self.level` is `[String]`. If yes, try using **id: \.self**

Thanks!

Comment: CardView(item: item, page: self.$page)
Had to change this, because forget to send the @binding $page...
However, after the launch the empty screen appears... what could it be?

Comment: Also changed *.self* for *$page* and other vars... a bit strange because we don't declare structures for .identifiers, however, it is being used.